# Val cannot be reassigned error in constructor

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to reassign a new value in the constructor, but I can't.

```
class InstantDate {

    private var date: LocalDateTime? = null

        constructor(date: String) {
        if (date.contains(" ")) 
        {
            date = date.replace(" ", "T")
            this.date = LocalDateTime.parse(date)
        }
    
    }

}
```

I get the error "val cannot be reassigned."

How can I solve this without creating a new value? Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean to assign to `this.date` instead of just `date`?

Comment: I updated the code, sorry. If there is a space in the date string, I want to delete it and assign it to the date string. In "this.date" I want to convert it to LocalDateTime.

Comment: You can't reassign a function parameter, you need to use another variable or do not create a variable at all. Also note your code does not assign any date if it doesn't contain the space.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods and constructor parameters are implicitly `val`s in Kotlin and cannot be re-assigned. Either create local `var`, or maybe inline your replace operation on string like so:

```kotlin
class InstantDate {
    private var date: LocalDateTime? = null
    
    constructor(date: String) {
        if (date.contains(" ")) {
            this.date = LocalDateTime.parse(date.replace(" ", "T"))
        }
    }
}
```